# How can I show anonymous users their own content?

Tags: views, 8, users

I've tried to reach this with views and https://www.drupal.org/project/session_node_access and https://www.drupal.org/project/views_extras with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't. The whole thing of being anonymous is that you aren't identified/identifiable. There is no way to associate anonymous content with a specific user. If content needs to be assigned to specific users, they can't be anonymous.

Comment: If you can give us more detail as to your goal, we may be able to provide more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous user is a user with `uid=0`. So *all* (repeat *all*) anonymous users have the same `uid` value, and therefor there is no way to do what you are asking for out of the box.

---

There are various techniques you could programmatically do, but of course they all have their limitations.

**Starting an anonymous session**. Here when the node is created you add the Node ID in a `$_SESSION` variable and you can use this to retrieve the Node ID and pass that to the views arguments. Obviously, the limitation is that as soon as you close the browser, the session ends and you can no longer tell if it's the same user. So you have to start the cycle again, create a new node, etc...

**Using cookies** same as above but with cookies. Once cookie expires or it's cleared it's over.

**Using IP** You would save the IP as a field in the Node and you can query the DB to retrieve the Node that belongs to that IP. Obviously, the limitation here is if the user's IP changes it ends here.

**Combination of all 3** Lastly, you could do all 3, have the other 2 as possible backups.

Comment: `there is no way to do what you are asking for.` @Jaypan also says, `If content needs to be assigned to specific users, they can't be anonymous.`  But... Commerce, which uses Views can show anonymous users their own order/cart view 

Comment: Interesting comment @NoSssweat (bonjour!) ... didn't know / realize that. If you have more info /details about ***how*** Commerce does that, then feel free to add (edit) that in my answer (or get the question reopened to post an extra answer!

Comment: They likely store it in a cookie/session - as carts often do. But this runs into the issues that Pierre lists - there is be no way to do it consistently, since once that cookie is lost, there is no way to associate the user back with their content. Consider logins - they expire when the cookie expires, and the user requires some sort of identifier to be able to tell the system who they are again. This is the username/password combination. Without a method to re-identifying the user, there is no way to re-associate their content. And if the user can identify themselves, they aren't anonymous.

Comment: merci for the edit @NoSssweat ! And to Jaypan also merci for the additional comment (if you want that edited in the answer also: please go ahead!